# How to determine the probability of an event, given that three events do not occur simultaneously..

Tags: probability

Three events A, B and C do not occur simultaneously. We know that 
$P(A\cap B)=P(B\cap C)=P(A\cap C)=\frac{1}{3}$

Please determine P(A).

Solution:
P(A) = 2/3

---

How would I go about to solve this question? I do not fully comprehend the meaning of the non-simultaneous occurrence in this question. Is it meant for pairs of 2 events happening at the same time, or is it meant that all events are disjoint?

Comment: It means $P(A\cap B\cap C) = 0$.

Comment: More strongly, it means that $A\cap B \cap C = \emptyset$, which of course has probability $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try drawing a Venn diagram. You'll realize that the events $A \cap B$, $B \cap C$, and $A \cap C$ are exhaustive and mutually exclusive, so it must be just the sum of the probabilities for the events involving $A$. To see this, notice that:
\begin{align*}
P(A) &\geq P((A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C)) & \text{since } (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C) \subseteq A \\
&= P(A \cap B) + (A \cap C) & \text{since } P(A \cap B \cap C) = 0\\
&= 1/3 + 1/3 \\
&= 2/3
\end{align*}
and:
\begin{align*}
P(A) &= 1 - P(\overline A) \\
&\leq 1 - P(B \cap C)  \qquad \text{since } A \cap B \cap C = \emptyset \implies B \cap C  \subseteq \overline A \\
&= 1 - 1/3 \\
&= 2/3
\end{align*}
so $P(A) = 2/3$.

Answer (score 0):

Given

$$P(A \cap B) = P(B \cap C) = P(A \cap C) = \frac{1}{3}$$

We can see

$$P(A \cap B) + P(B \cap C) + P(A \cap C) = 1$$

Now since

$$P(A \cap B \cap C) = 0$$

We know that exactly one of three events must occur:

Ether $(A \cap B)$ or $(A \cap C)$ or $(B \cap C)$. And no other outcome is possible.

Note: if $P(A \cap B \cap C) \neq 0$ then other possibilities may have existed because the sets would be joint and event $A$ on its own may have been possible for example but since we have proved that the sets are disjoint and since the combined probability adds to 1 no other outcomes are possible.

Thus

$$P(A) = P(A \cap B) \cup P(A \cap C) = \frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3} = \frac{2}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

The event that *at least* two of the three events $A,B,C$ occur is $AB \cup AC \cup BC$, and by the principle of inclusion/exclusion,
$$\begin{align}
P(AB \cup AC \cup BC) &= P(AB) + P(AC) + P(BC) -P(ABC)-P(ABC)-P(ABC) + P(ABC)\\
&= P(AB)+P(AC)+P(BC)-0-0-0+0\\
&= 1.
\end{align}$$
It follows that the probability of the 
*complementary* event $-$ that *at least* two of the three events $A^c, B^c, C^c$
occur $-$ is $0$, and so the four subsets $AB^cC^c, A^cBC^c, A^cB^cC, A^cB^cC^c$ of the
complementary event also have probability $0$.

Next, note that $P(ABC^c) = P(AB) - P(ABC) =  P(AB)-0  = \frac{1}{3}$, and similarly,
$P(AB^cC) = P(A^cBC) = \frac{1}{3}$ also.   Hence, 
$$\begin{align}P(A) &= P(ABC) + P(ABC^c) + P(AB^cC) + P(AB^cC^c)\\
&= 0 + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} + 0\\
&= \frac{2}{3}.
\end{align}$$